# Exclude __builtin__ module

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, built-in

The `__builtin__` module in Python clutters a developers namespace with lots of functions and classes that have very generic names (e.g. `max`, `sum`, `id`, `hash` etc.) that often get in the way of naming variables and when outside of a context-aware IDE one can accidentally overwrite a name without noticing.

Is there a way to stop this module from being implicitly accessed from a certain file and require explicit imports instead?

Something along the lines of:

```
from __builtins__ import hash as builtin_hash

hash = builtin_hash(foo)
```

I am aware that this is bad practice.

Comment: ...seriously? You want to have to explicitly import `list` and `int` and `True` and `False` and `dict` and every other built-in name you use? That's not going to stop you from accidentally name-clashing with a built-in anyway.

Comment: Honestly if you really want to shadow a builtin like `id` you can, you don't need to delete it first?

Comment: There are a few slightly different things you could be asking for here. (1) Can you remove `__builtin__`/`__builtins__` so that from now on the current global scope has no access to builtins? (2) Can you prevent it from being created for a particular new global scope or for all new global scopes? (3) Can you do (2) at startup, so it even affects your top-level script or REPL? (4) Can you change Python to just never look in `globals()['__builtins__']` or equivalent when doing `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `LOAD_NAME` lookups? So, which of those do you actually want? (You _shouldn't_ want any of them…)

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to contradict your last paragraph—you start off arguing that this would be a good thing to do because Python is wrong, and then you say you know it's a bad thing to do.

Comment: Since people seem to be downvoting this I would like to note that downvotes are [for low-effort or non-researched questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) and I have found no resource on this topic.

Comment: @abarnert What I mean by "I am aware that this is bad practice." is that I am aware that excluding builtins from a namespace is something that should not be done in a proper project.

Comment: @PhilippPloder Well, there is the fact that `__builtin__` is a Python 2-ism in a Python 3 question, but yeah, that's probably not why people are downvoting.

Comment: So if you're aware that it should not be done in a proper project, what's with all the argument that it clutters the namespace of a module, etc., which surely is only going to matter in a proper project?

Comment: @abarnert I see. Apparently Python 2 and 3 approach the builtins very differently. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Part of what I'm trying to get at here is that I think this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The actual problem is that you're worried about accidentally shadowing builtins, but you're asking about your attempted solution to that problem instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167299/discussion-between-philipp-ploder-and-abarnert).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply delete [`__builtins__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution), the name Python uses to find the built-in namespace:

```
>>> del __builtins__
>>> max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'max' is not defined
```

*Warning*: If you do this in someone else's namespace, they will hate you.

> ...and require explicit imports instead?

Note that import statements are resolved using builtins  ;)

```
>>> del __builtins__
>>> from builtins import max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: __import__ not found
```

> ... very generic names (e.g. max, sum, id, hash etc.) that often get in the way of naming variables and when outside of a context-aware IDE one can accidentally overwrite a name without noticing

You will only create a local variable which shadows the name.  This is actually fairly inconsequential if you do it from within a limited scope, although it's still bad form (readability counts).

```
# this shadows built-in hash function in this namespace ... meh?
hash = '38762cf7f55934b34d179ae6a4c80cadccbb7f0a'

# this stomps built-in hash ... not a honking great idea!
import builtins
builtins.hash = lambda obj: -1
```

Best practice:

- Use a context-aware editor which will give you a squiggly underline for name collisions, or
- Use Python long enough that you know the built-in names by heart (seriously!)
- Avoid name shadowing by using a synonym (e.g. `checksum`) or appending a trailing underscore on the name (e.g. `hash_`)

Comment: A few things to note: first, this is going to break the `import` statement by rendering `__import__` unavailable, even if you explicitly set `__import__ = __import__` first; I believe `__import__` needs to be found through `__builtins__`. Second, you should probably explain the relationship between `__builtins__` and `builtins`/`__builtin__`.

Comment: According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) `__builtins__` is a CPython implementation detail

Comment: @PhilippPloder True. It works for CPython and PyPy, but may not work for the other 0 major implementations of Python 3. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure (I'll check when I get back to my laptop) that this won't work in iPython—or, rather, it'll only work until you get to the next input prompt.

Comment: You haven't really addressed the "require explicit imports" part (i.e. `import builtins` should probably appear somewhere in your answer)

Comment: @Aran-Fey If the OP really hates the way Python name lookup works, maybe he'd be happier with something `builtins = types.SimpleNamespace(__builtins__)` instead. That way `builtins.__builtins__` doesn't get used, so you can `del builtins.max` properly to break your session even further.

Comment: @PhilippPloder I was mostly joking with that comment; it really is worth paying attention to those notes even if it doesn't matter in 2018. Imagine if you'd written code for 2.5 that relied on implementation details of CPython and Jython because nothing else exists, and then a year later you started getting bug reports that your library doesn't work with PyPy and IronPython…

Comment: I'm not sure the discussion of shadowing makes it clear enough that everything the OP is trying to do to work around accidental shadowing with "delete builtins and explicitly import" can be done exactly the same way with "just leave builtins alone but still explicitly import".

Comment: Or, to put it another way: He's trying to solve the problem of accidentally making `hash` inaccessible by intentionally making `hash` inaccessible, which doesn't actually do anything. It's the thing he does _after_ that which solves the problem, and he didn't need the first step for the second one.

Comment: PS, wim, do you really know the names of all builtins by heart? I'm pretty sure if you quizzed me there's a couple I'd miss. (But I can find them in the REPL, or call up the docs in my browser, in a couple seconds, so I don't need to have a memory…)

Comment: There's no way I could list them exhaustively by heart (the whole exception heirarchy is in there!), but I think I could tell if a given name is shadowing a builtin name by heart, with pretty good accuracy.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Reread the OP's first paragraph and tell me he'd never actually advocate this.